# Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке c++ возможности прочитать файл целиком в std::string или std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке c++ возможности прочитать файл целиком в std::string или std::vector, не прибегая при этом к построчному или посимвольному чтению файла в цикле?

Comment: Можно вызвать один раз `ifstream::read`.

Comment: std::istream_iterator<char>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    ifstream buffer("test.txt");
    string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(buffer)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream buffer("test.txt");
    stringstream str;
    str << buffer.rdbuf();
    string fileInfo(str.str());
    cout << fileInfo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ещё способы, но эти достаточно простые и удобные

Comment: Это как раз способы, прибегающие к посимвольному чтению. Причем кривые и неудобные.

Comment: Второй способ очень быстрый и непосимвольный.

Comment: @user7860670, я понял автора, как просьбу дать ему способ чтения файла практически в одну строчку без написания своего цикла.